# What's the point of Terraform's modules?

Tags: terraform

I'm a bit curious about Terraform's modules. What exactly are their points? I keep seeing it is supposed to save me time, no copy paste, and such, but I think I might be missing the point because I don't see why I would use them?

I have used them only once so my experience is limited. I have to create 2 different environments and I'm not sure why I would go for it. Maybe I would have a different opinion if I had to do 10 environments.
The environments will be in different accounts, using different vpcs, different IAM, ... Which led me to think I could create basically 2 folders and reference some variables.

Regarding the "no copy-paste", it seems to me you do a file which then refers to the modules and the variables. At some point, you still need to write all the ressources (int-sg, test-sg for example). so why not write it directly into the right folder?

I hope this question makes sense, I would appreciate any constructive opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modules are indented to group resources that are required multiple times.

Let's say you have the three environments `dev`, `staging` and `prod`.
You would want to keep them as equal as possible, especially `staging` and `prod`.

So, if you want to create a server with an EIP, certain security groups and whatever it needs to be accessible, you can create a module to group these resources.
The module can then easily be included in your `.tf` files for the respective environments with *different parameters* for each env.

So you can keep the resources very generic, and also have the avantage that Terraform will automatically update all environments equally in case you change resources in the module.
You'll thus have a single point where to apply modifications, instead of editing all changed resources in all env files.

Now only imagine you have more than 2 or 3 environments (or use cases for the same resource groups) and you'll see the advantage of modules ;)